# Getting type error in python

Tags: python, class, error-handling

I am using a class based service in python and I get error whenever I want to use it. Unable to figure out the reason.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from xml.dom import minidom
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
from pysimplesoap.helpers import sort_dict

MEDIA_ROOT = '/User/sunand/documents/resumes/'
parser = ResumeParser()
names = parser.get_names(MEDIA_ROOT)
print names


class ParserClient(SoapClient):

""" Extends the soap client to encode the response with utf-8 encoding.
"""

def wsdl_call(
    self,
    method,
    *args,
    **kwargs
    ):
    """ Override wsdl_call method to make sure unmarshall is not called.
    """

    operation = self.get_operation(method)

    # get i/o type declarations:

    inp = operation['input']
    header = operation.get('header')
    if 'action' in operation:
        self.action = operation['action']

    # construct header and parameters

    if header:
        self.__call_headers = sort_dict(header, self.__headers)
    (method, params) = self.wsdl_call_get_params(method, inp,
            *args, **kwargs)

    response = self.call(method, *params)
    return response

def send(self, method, xml):
    """ Overrides the send method to get the actual xml content.
    """

    content = super(ParserClient, self).send(method, xml)
    self.result = content
    return content
class ResumeParser(object):

""" Connects to the Resume Parser's XML api to get parsed data.
"""

def __init__(self, simple=True, timeout=60):
    """ Initializes the ResumeParser class.
    """

    self.wsdl = \
        'http://jobsite.onlineresumeparser.com/rPlusParseResume.asmx?WSDL'
    self.secret = 'my-secret-key'  # Enter key here
    self.encoding = 'base64'
    self.simple = simple
    self.client = ParserClient(wsdl=self.wsdl, timeout=timeout)
    self.names = []

def get_file_content(self, file_path):
    """ Return the encoded content for the given file.
    """

    file_obj = open(os.path.abspath(file_path), 'r')
    content = file_obj.read().encode(self.encoding)
    file_obj.close()

    return content

def get_names(self, path):
    """
    Given a path to a folder that contains resume files this method
    will parse the resumes and will return the names of the candidates
    as a list.
    """

    opt = os.path
    resumes = [opt.join(path, r) for r in os.listdir(path)
               if opt.isfile(opt.join(path, r))]

    # Parse information for each resume.

    for resume in resumes:
        try:
            xml_data = self.get_xml(resume)
            name = self.get_name_from_xml(xml_data)
            if name:
                self.names.append(name)
        except Exception, err:

                # print name

            print 'Error parsing resume: %s' % str(err)

    return list(set(self.names))

def get_name_from_xml(self, data):
    """ Returns the full name from the xml data given.
    """

    xmldata = minidom.parseString(data)
    name = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('CANDIDATE_FULL_NAME')
    name = name[0].childNodes[0].data.title()

    return name

def get_xml(self, filepath):
    """ Fetches and returns the xml for the given file from the api.
    """

    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

    extension = os.path.splitext(filepath)[1]

    base64 = self.get_file_content(filepath)

    filedata = {
        'B64FileZippedContent': base64,
        'FileName': filename,
        'InputType': extension,
        'UserID': 1,
        'secretKey': self.secret,
        }

    get = \
        (self.client.GetSimpleXML if self.simple else self.client.getHRXML)
    get(**filedata)

    return self.process_raw_xml()

def process_raw_xml(self, data=None):
    """ Processes and returns the clean XML.
    """

    raw = (data if data else self.client.result)
    parsed = minidom.parseString(raw)
    result = parsed.getElementsByTagName('GetSimpleXMLResult')[0]
    text_node = result.childNodes[0]
    data = text_node.data.encode('UTF-8')

    return data
```

Upon running the code I am getting an error
TypeError: wsdl_call_get_params() got an unexpected keyword argument 'secretKey'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? It's hard to find the place of your error from a first look. Also, indent your code properly

Comment: Include how you use `ParseClient` in your example. There are no calls to `wsdl_call` currently, so it is impossible to say this or that about `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: The only thing I am getting is Error parsing resume: wsdl_call_get_params() got an unexpected keyword argument 'secretKey'

Comment: @IljaEverilä That's the complete code. While debugging I see `header = operation.get('header')` outputs a blank dict.

Comment: Whatever is calling wsdl_call is sending a keyword arg in secretKey. Did you write this code?

Comment: @Trent No, I have not written this code. But while using it, I am facing this issue.

Comment: This is absolutely the only file you are running? I can't see how wsdl_call_get_params is even being called...

Comment: @Trent Yes, this is the only file I am ruuning. I am using http://www.onlineresumeparser.com/Product/ResumeParserWebAPIIntegrationWithPython

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are incorrectly overriding `wsdl_call`.

Firstly, we can see that [`SoapClient`](https://github.com/fuzeman/pysimplesoap/blob/master/pysimplesoap/client.py) (which you extend in `ParserClient`), has a `__getattr__` function that fetches pseudo-attributes of the `SoapClient`.

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    "Return a pseudo-method that can be called"
    if not self.services: # not using WSDL?
        return lambda self=self, *args, **kwargs: self.call(attr,*args,**kwargs)
    else: # using WSDL:
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.wsdl_call(attr,*args,**kwargs)
```

You can see that this function is using `wsdl_call` to help it map functions to unknown attributes.

The specific pseudo-method that is causing the problem is in your code (or appears to be):

```
filedata = {
    'B64FileZippedContent': base64,
    'FileName': filename,
    'InputType': extension,
    'UserID': 1,
    'secretKey': self.secret, # <-- the secretKey key word argument
    }

get = \
    (self.client.GetSimpleXML if self.simple else self.client.getHRXML)
get(**filedata)
# here client is an instance of your `ParserClient` (and `SoapClient`).
```

This above bit took me a while to track down. With a full stack trace I would have found it much quicker. Please always post stack traces (when there is one) in future when asking for help.

#### How to solve this

- Provide a concrete implementation of `GetSimpleXML` and `getHRXML`. This will solve the immediate problem, but not the larger problem.
- Rewrite `wsdl_call`

The rewritten section of code should check the value of the `method` argument and either do what you want, or delegate to the `SoapClient` implementation.

eg.

```
def wsdl_call(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
    if method == "some_method":
        return self._my_wsdl_call(method, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return super(ParserClient, self).wsdl_call(method, *args, **kwargs)

def _my_wsdl_call(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```